# Angular-xeditable checkbox in table display below row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, x-editable

I have a table that is using `Angular-xeditable` to do some in-line editing, but when I include a checkbox it places it to the left and down further than it should be.  I have created a plunk that is not working 100% but you can see the checkbox being shown in the incorrect location.  Here is the plunk

> https://plnkr.co/edit/Z6DA2Jovl0LxRH9Fu4PH?p=preview

I noticed when trying to create this plunk that if I do not have this code
`app.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3'; // bootstrap3 theme. Can be also 'bs2', 'default'
});`

Then the checkbox will appear in the column displayed as predicted but it is needed for many of the features and styling, desired for the rest of the application.

Anyone have a lot of experience with `xeditable` that they might know a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not the best solution, but I've overhidden the editable-checkbox css, as below:

```
.editable-checkbox {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I know that this may not be the best solution but it works for what I need it to do so thank you so much!